# Is there a quick way to fold and unfold comments in xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, xcode7-beta5, xcode7-beta6

Is there a quick way to fold and unfold a block of comments in xcode 7?

While I'm trying out new code I like to keep different versions of a "solution" until I decide which one is my favorite and delete the rejected material.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fold blocks of comments in Swift using Xcode the way I do it in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573269/how-can-i-fold-blocks-of-comments-in-swift-using-xcode-the-way-i-do-it-in-visual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code-folding block comments does not work in Xcode 7 - 7.2.1 in Swift files.

You can, however, hack it by using an empty closure to surround the comments. This will also work with multiple line comments too.

```
_ = { /* Comment
      myCommented.code
      */ }
```

Definitely a hack, but could save you lots of scrolling around.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. This looks like a practical way of doing it until Apple releases a fix.

Answer (score 5):

### The ability to Fold & Unfold code blocks is set to OFF within Xcode 7.

#### Steps to change this:

1. Select **Xcode** (top left)
2. Choose **Preferences**
3. Navigate to **Text Editing** (center)
4. ***Tick*** the option **Code folding ribbon**

Once you've done this, you'll be able to collapse the comments, along with blocks of code.

I hope this helps!

.

***Added Picture Reference***

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - this was default ON for me then all of a sudden turned OFF.  Was looking for your solution.